# Can't define variables when calling "/usr/bin/env bash" with execve()

Tags: c, bash, exec

I want to execute `/usr/bin/env` and print out `a=11` and `b=22`. Currently, what I have:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
void main() {
    char *name[3];
    name[0]="/usr/bin/env";
    name[1]="bash";
    name[2]=NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

I can run it perfectly as it opens a bash shell.

However, I'm trying to define and print `a=11` and `b=22`. When trying to define `a=11`, I'm doing:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
void main() {
    char *name[4];
    name[0]="/usr/bin/env";
    name[1]="bash";
    name[2]="a=11";
    name[3]=NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

And it returns this error:

```
bash: a=11: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know that you don't need `/usr/bin/env` to set environment variables. You can just make a copy of the current environment (which is in the global `environ`) and add your new assignments to the end of it. Then pass it as the third argument of `execve`. If you're not going to pass a new environment, there's no point using `execve`. You could just use `execv` (or `execvp` if you want to do a path lookup for `bash`).

Comment: What you are doing is equivalent to writing on the command line `bash a=11`. The first non-option argument of bash denotes the **program** to be executed (for instance, 'bash myscript.sh`. Therefore bash searches for a file named `a=11` to be executed. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve here in the end, and whether you want the variable `a` to end up in bash as environment or non-environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where are you expecting the variables to be printed, but you need something like this

```
name[0]="/usr/bin/env";
name[1]="a=11";
name[2]="b=22";
name[3]="bash";
name[4]="-c";
name[5]="printf \"%d %d\\n\" $a $b";
name[6]=NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first non-option argument to `bash` is expected to be the name of a script to execute.

To execute a command using `bash`, you would use the `-c` option.

For example, to execute

```sh
a=11; printf '%s\n' "$a"
```

one would use

```sh
bash -c 'a=11; printf '\''%s\n'\'' "$a"'
```

So the C code is

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void main(void) {
    char *name[3];
    name[0] = "bash";
    name[1] = "-c";
    name[2] = "a=11; printf '%s\n' \"$a\"';
    execvpe(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

Replaced `execve` with `execvpe` to avoid having to use `env`.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of `env`'s arguments. It expects variable assignments (`a=11`) to precede the command (`bash`).

```
name[0]="/usr/bin/env";
name[1]="a=11";
name[2]="bash";
name[3]=NULL;
```

Per the [env(1) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
       env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
DESCRIPTION
       Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I wasn't defining a and b before bash, and there was the error. Thank you all!